# What active Linux / embedded Linux forums are available online?

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux

What active Linux / embedded Linux forums are available online?

Comment: There are many more forums but thay are often bound to different architecture. Specify CPU/MCU if you want more links.

Comment: I am working on ARM processor.

Comment: But the idea with a generic emb linux forum is good...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the Linux Devices Web site with a forum: http://forums.linuxfordevices.com/

Linux Questions : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-embedded-78/

Embedded.com also has forum:
http://www.embedded.com/tigforums/forum.jspa?forumID=23  (not specifically linux, but more focused on overall embedded systems; so I am sure there are embedded linux discussions)

and if you are using a TI processor, TI has their community forum with specifics for their chips:
https://community.ti.com/forums/

Answer (score 2):

Well, I would like to add a couple of Blogs along with a few groups which I have subscribed and simply love it :)

[**Linux Kernel Newbies group**](http://groups.google.com/group/linuxkernelnewbies?hl=en)

For Linux on ARM, subscribe to **ARM Linux Mailing list** [ groups.google.com/group/linuxkernelnewbies?hl=en ]

Also subscribe to these excellent Blogs on Linux - **The Geek Stuff** [ www.thegeekstuff.com ] and **Linux Admin Blog** [ www.cyberciti.biz ]

Last but not the least, along with the suggestions[about forums] given by others; do subscribe to the individual mailing lists of components[like uboot, Mplayer, Firefox etc.] which you might be focusing on

Hope you find this list helpful.

-hjsblogger

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to Linux kernel Newbies group.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [comp.os.linux.embedded](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/comp.os.linux.embedded/topics) and [comp.arch.embedded](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/comp.arch.embedded/topics)

They are active but not as hot as SO :)

Comment: Sadly, all of usenet is less hot anymore because comcast and verizon don't provide it, because it was publicized that kiddy porn was posted there.

Answer (score 1):

Have also a look at:
http://www.at91.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are some smaller forums associated with the different embedded linux cards, but non of them seem to be that generic. (I'm thinking about projects like NGW100, LinuxStamp, BeagleBoard, GumStick and others)

One of the more generic forum seem to be StackOverflow, not the biggest forum in the field but sometimes you get some good answers here.